# Breaking Stuff and Putting it Back Together

Tags: energy, entropy

I was wondering if you could put something back together exactly the way it was before. It takes a certain amount of energy to break something, so theoretically could you put it back together exactly with that same energy. For example, you rip a piece of paper in half which used energy. Using that same energy could you put it back together?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that it would take energy to put stuff back together, but there's a problem. When something breaks or gets ripped, things get very messy at the atomic level. In plastics, the molecular chains are unravelled; in rigid objects, planes of atoms are slipped past each other and locked into new positions, etc. It's not just a matter of energy. You would have to somehow manipulate atoms to get them back into their original places.

Comment: Are there any clear bounds on the entropy increase here that would allow us to calculate how much energy is needed to fix the bonds? For example, ripping apart a $N$ atom chain (1 state) into two leads to $N-1$ possible states depending on where the break is, and hence has entropy $\log(N-1)$. So presumably we would need to pay $kT\log(N-1)$ J extra to fix it?